# How to transform global attribution Markov Chains results into transaction-level for real-time revenue attribution?

Tags: r, markov-chains, attribution

I'm currently building a data-driven attribution model for my company. It relies on Markov Chains, and I have used the package ChannelAttribution in R which is great!

It gave me results at global level: what is the weight of every channel on total conversions and revenue. But now I have to move towards deployment phase in the systems.

To do that, I need that every new transaction happening gets its revenue distributed on channels in the path. My problem is that Markov Model for attribution is not a "predictive" model so there is no output at the transaction level (it basically simulates paths to calculate removal effects so no granular info).

Does anyone have an idea on how to translate the global output of the model into a set of rules that would allow for distributing revenue of new transactions in real time (or approx. real time like everyday)? I guess there can be additional hypothesis or another layer of modelling that could do the trick but I can't put my finger on it.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

Baptiste